# Trying to de-folder all applications in my dash menu

Tags: gnome, icons, 21.10, gnome-dash

Please can anyone suggest to me a "Applications' folder Management" tool ??
i wanna to **de-folder all applications(remove all folders and view applications separately) in my dash menu**...

- Please note that I can't de-folder every application manually as it will take a lot of time (100+ applications)

---

### System Specifications

- Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10
- Life cycle: Non-LTS
- Architecture: AMD64
- Gnome Version: 40.4.0
- Windowing System: Wayland
- GTK version: 4.4.0
- Adwaita version: 1.0.0
- GStreamer version: 1.19.1
- GJS version: 1.68.4

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain how you managed to get folders in your dash (it's called "dash", not "dash menu"). It's also unclear why you want hundreds of applications in your dash -- that makes it much harder to use. Most folks use the Desktop Search (aka Overlay Mode) to store all those seldom-used applications. See the [Gnome Shell nomeclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) diagram.

Comment: @Zorono I think you may achieve that with this command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/` https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYvwR.png

Comment: @UnKNOWn thank you, dude :D that worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

From a comment by [PRATAP](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/pratap), use:

```sh
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/
```

For reference: [image]